# How do we use the facebook React addons Perf class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying a very simple thing, and am getting errors "TypeError: Cannot read property 'counts' of undefined"

Here's the hello world example code.

https://gist.github.com/joshuacalloway/ae5b184c485956314d1c

Comment: I got this to work, by using the javascript console.  Also I noticed that React.addons.Perf.printWasted() throws that error when no measurements have been collected yet

Comment: If you've solved your own issue, you should post an answer to your question and accept it so that others can easily know that it has been solved.

Comment: I think it's an issue with React.addons.Perf class.  As of 0.13 the class was throwing that TypeError when no measurements were taken.   A more "Human Readable" would have been to show a warning message of sort that "No measurements available yet."

Answer (score 18):

I know this question is old - but in case someones fall in here (as I did) here it's how you should do it nowdays..

You import the react addon you want separately

```
import Perf from 'react-addons-perf'
```

and then you can do whatever you want with it..
Example: Assign it to the window object so you can use it in the console.

```
window.Perf = Perf
```

Comment: This helped me:
`componentDidMount() {
  window.Perf = Perf;
}`

Comment: This is not working for me. I am doing exactly this and my object just has:  {enableMeasure: false, injection: Object}, and nothing else. I can start or stop it. Any ideas?

Comment: @jamesemanon im getting exactly the same error, can you let me know if you figure it out n i'll do likewise

Comment: @jamesemanon this sorted it for me: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6174#issuecomment-230569698
 versions of `react` and `react-addons-perf` need to be the same

Answer (score 5):

I was getting the same error calling Perf.start() in the render function where I wanted to start profiling, seemed to be a timing issue, so I just started recording perf before I rendered anything and then called my print functions when I wanted to see what was going on (pseudocode):

In app.js:

```
//var React = require('react'); // DONOTCHECKIN
var React = require('react/addons');
// ...

function run() {
  // DONOTCHECKIN
  window.Perf = React.addons.Perf; // save for later console calls
  React.addons.Perf.start();
  // ...
```

Then in the console I can invoke:

```
Perf.printWasted()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you post a gist/github link of how you are profiling reactjs? It would be helpful for me.